# Combine tags [keyboard-shortcuts], [hotkeys], and [shortcut-key]

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

Suggesting to combine the following tags:

- [keyboard-shortcuts](/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts) : 1896
- [hotkeys](/questions/tagged/hotkeys) : 468
- [shortcut-key](/questions/tagged/shortcut-key) : 31

Comment: Voting to close - looks to be a [synonym-request] for Stack Overflow, not MSE.